# How to hide fields that belong to the model I'm inheriting from in django admin panel

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have these 2 models in my `models.py`

```
class Student(AbstractBaseUser):
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(null=True)

class Teacher(Student):
    bio = models.TextField(null=True)
    image = CompressedImageField(null=True, blank=True, default="default.png")
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

Now in admin panel when i go to edit the Teacher instance I display only bio image and student. The issue is that also display those fields when I try to edit Teacher instance but entering from Student model. So is there a way for that?

P.S the models and fields may not make sense because they are examples.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ModelAdmin.fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fields) or [`ModelAdmin.exclude`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.exclude) to control which fields you want to include or exclude in the admin site form.

```py
from django.contrib import admin

class TeacherAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ("date_of_birth", "phone_number")
```

And register it like so

```py
admin.site.register(Teacher, TeacherAdmin)
```